# Does rmarkdown allow captions and references for code chunks?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a trick for captioning and referencing a chuck of code in rmarkdown (not the result of running the code)? For example, how do I reference this block of code:

````
```{r blah}
blah <- "blah"
```
````

I know that I can use \@ref(fig:theFig) or \@ref(tab:theTable) to get at fig.cap or caption (with kable) but I don't see a way to caption and reference the code itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This would be a great feature. And I think it is not integrated yet. Here is an approach that works for PDF documents and allows you to generate captions as well as labels for cross-referencing:

1. Include a `header.tex` with the following content

---

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareNewFloatType{chunk}{placement=H, fileext=chk, name=}
\captionsetup{options=chunk}
\renewcommand{\thechunk}{Chunk~\thesection.\arabic{chunk}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chunk}{section}
\makeatother
```

Since the environment used for chunks is not a floating type we declare a new one, named `chunk`. The option `name` is left blank since we already redefine `\thechunk` in the next line by prepending the word *Chunk* (play with the name option and see what happens).

The chunks should be enumerated by section and so we tell tex to reset the counter each time a new section begins.

If you do not use section numbering (by setting the YAML option), then replace the line

```
\renewcommand{\thechunk}{Chunk~\thesection.\arabic{chunk}}
```

by

```
\renewcommand{\thechunk}{Chunk~\arabic{chunk}}
```

2. Modify the knitr source hook in your rmarkdown document

---

```
library(knitr)
oldSource <- knit_hooks$get("source")
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- oldSource(x, options)
  x <- ifelse(!is.null(options$ref), paste0("\\label{", options$ref,"}", x), x)
  ifelse(!is.null(options$codecap), paste0("\\captionof{chunk}{", options$codecap,"}", x), x)
})
```

Here we make use of two new chunk options `ref` and `codecap`. If either one is not `NULL`, a corresponding label or caption is generated using the the commands `\label` or `\captionof`.

**MWE:**

````
---
title: "Cross-referencing Code Chunks"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    number_sections: true
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
oldSource <- knit_hooks$get("source")
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- oldSource(x, options)
  x <- ifelse(!is.null(options$ref), paste0("\\label{", options$ref,"}", x), x)
  ifelse(!is.null(options$codecap), paste0("\\captionof{chunk}{", options$codecap,"}", x), x)
})
```

# Foo

Jump to \ref{TheBarChunk}

```{r Foo, ref = "TheFooChunk", codecap = "My Chunk"}
print("Foo!")
```

\newpage

# Bar

```{r Bar, ref = "TheBarChunk", codecap = "My second chunk"}
print("Bar!")
```

Head back to \ref{TheFooChunk}
````

Here is the output (of both pages):

[image]

[image]

#### Adding the caption *below* the code chunk

If you'd prefer to add the caption *below* the code chunk, *instead of* above, this can be achieved by altering the above knitr hook to read:

```
oldSource <- knit_hooks$get("source")
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
  x <- oldSource(x, options)
  x <- ifelse(!is.null(options$codecap), paste0(x, "\\captionof{chunk}{", options$codecap,"}"), x)
  ifelse(!is.null(options$ref), paste0(x, "\\label{", options$ref,"}"), x)
})
```

**Comments:**

You could improve the code by checking what output type is desired so that the new source hook is only used for pdf output (skipped since it is lunch time).

Comment: Thanks for a great solution. Is there an easy alteration to make to append the caption _below_ the code-chunk, instead of above? I've had a go at it but can't get it working. Cheers.

Comment: Check the position argument in http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-deu.pdf. That might work.

Comment: The position argument only alters the spacing around the caption. From the documentation you linked: "Please note that position=bottom does NOT mean that the caption is actually placed at the bottom...".

Comment: However, I since found that swapping the order of the arguments of the `paste0`  command is sufficient to position the caption below. ie. `paste0(x, "\\label{", options$ref,"}")` and `paste0(x, "\\captionof{chunk}{", options$codecap,"}")`.

Comment: This also works for [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/). `header.txt` and the `knitr` source hook chunk need no modification. The YAML header just needs to replace `pdf_document:` with `bookdown::pdf_book:`. No need to include `number_sections: true` in the YAML header, because bookdown numbers sections by default.

Note that no numbering will occur unless you include the `codecap` chunk option, even if you included `ref`.

Comment: After further testing, it seems to break `\parskip` after displaying a caption (after the first captioned code chunk, paragraphs no longer have any spacing between them). Seems to be related to [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366236/captionof-destroys-parskip). Solution seems to be to put the `\captionof` command inside an environment. Suggestions on how to implement that here?

Comment: I may have some time next weekend to put my answer under review ;)

Comment: @CarolineRing Following [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237216/163196), if there is a `captionof` added, surrounding the source `x` with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` seems to do the trick: `paste0("\\begingroup\\captionof{chunk}{", options$codecap,"}", x, "\\endgroup")`

Comment: Is there a similar solution for HTML documents?